# 2-D array(Matrix) layer rotation code. Trying to optimise a code for matrix layer rotation

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array

I was trying to write a code to rotate a given matrix `a`, `int r` times which is passed to the function as an argument. My code is correct but it gives TLE in some cases. Can anyone optimise this code?
The function rotates the matrix by `1` step `r` number of times. If `r = 1` it will rotate a matrix that looks like this

```
   1 2 3
   4 5 6
   7 8 9
to
   2 3 6 
   1 5 9 
   4 7 8
```

The matrix can go upto `n * m`. In which every layer will be rotated by `r`.

```
void matrixRotation(vector<vector<int>> a, int r){
    //rotates matrix by 1 r times
    while(r>0){
    int top=0, left=0, bottom=a.size()-1, right=a[0].size()-1;  
    //keep the loops in limit 
    while(top<bottom && left<right){
        int temp=a[top][left+1];                     
        //storing last element of the cycle
        for(int i=top; i<bottom; i++){
            swap(a[i][left],temp);
        }
        for(int i=left; i<right; i++){
            swap(a[bottom][i],temp);
        }
        for(int i=bottom; i>top; i--){
            swap(a[i][right],temp);
        }
        for(int i=right; i>left; i--){
            swap(a[top][i],temp);
        }
        top++;  left++; bottom--;   right--;
    }
    r--;
   }
    //Prints the matrix
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<a[i].size();j++){
            cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to rotate each row to the right position in one go, not by rotating by 1 step `r` times. Also, make use of [`std::rotate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate).

Comment: Can the matrices be bigger than 3x3? In that case, how much each layer rotates, by the same amount of `r`?

Comment: yes, It can be n*m where each layer will be rotated by r and @ G. Sliepen Ty for the idea bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optmisitiion: A ring(any layer) of a matrix m * n can only have 2*(m+n-2) possible rotations. That means we only need to rotate the ring of the matrix by
a maximum of 2*(m+n-2)-1 in worst case. I've noticed that as we go into the inner rings (layers) the number of rotations required is reduced by 8 (I've verified
it with examples). There are few exceptions such as a matrix of 3 * 5 or 5 * 3 or any matrix that has a 1D array left at the cetre (That case could be solved by
adding an extra if case in the code as it follows the same pattern until it gets to the innermost layer). But since there was a constraint min(m,n)%2==0, we wont
face that exception. so, as the maximum number of rotations in worst cases can be only 2*(m+n-2)-1, 2*(m+n-2)-9, 2*(m+n-2)-17,... we can find the rotations we
need to do by r%2*(m+n-2), r%2*(m+n-2)-8, r%2*(m+n-2)-16,... Adding it into code will look like.

```
void matrixRotation(vector<vector<int>> a, int r){
    
    int n=2*(a.size()+a[0].size()-2);
    int top=0, left=0, bottom=a.size()-1, right=a[0].size()-1; 
    while(top<bottom && left<right) {
     int rotation=r%n;
    while(rotation>0){
        int temp=a[top][left+1];                     

        for(int i=top; i<bottom; i++){
            swap(a[i][left],temp);
        }
        for(int i=left; i<right; i++){
            swap(a[bottom][i],temp);
        }
        for(int i=bottom; i>top; i--){
            swap(a[i][right],temp);
        }
        for(int i=right; i>left; i--){
            swap(a[top][i],temp);
        }
        rotation--;
    }
    top++;  left++; bottom--;   right--;    n-=8;
   }

    //Prints the matrix
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<a[i].size();j++){
            cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}
```